# Find and replace a word in a character array

Tags: c++, console-application, arrays

How would I go about finding the location of a word in a character array, and then replacing that word with another word?

Comment: Split the sentence into words, replace the word, join the words again, or use a regular expression.

Comment: You should include some sample code showing us what you have attempted.

Comment: Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of a character array and [`string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a character array I recommend using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). This will prevent you from having to implement the logic of doing the actual search and replace and possibly buffer management if the new string ends up being larger. `std::string` includes member functions for [searching](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [replacing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) elements within a string.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string haystack = "jack be nimble jack be blah blah blah";
    static const std::string needle = "nimble";

    std::cout << "before: " << haystack << std::endl;

    // Find the word in the string
    std::string::size_type pos = haystack.find(needle);

    // If we find the word we replace it.
    if(pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        haystack.replace(pos, needle.size(), "drunk");
    }

    std::cout << "after: " << haystack << std::endl;
}
```

This produces the following output

> before: jack be nimble jack be blah blah blah
>   after: jack be drunk jack be blah blah blah

Comment: @Fearless, it it solved it, mark it as solved. (click on check mark)